# Can Serverfault better show whether or not a question has any accepted answers?

Tags: feature-request

On Meta, Stackoverflow, and Superuser, when a question has an answer that has been accepted, its answer count is displayed as light against a dark background.  On Serverfault, this difference is much less obvious -- the color of the box around the count changes to a darker shade of green, and the number is displayed in green as well.

I'm not colorblind, but this is still subtle enough that I have to look really closely, where on the other sites, the difference is obvious.

It would be a lot easier for me, personally, if Serverfault used the same scheme as the other sites.  Does anybody else think the same?

Comment: I am colorblind and have thought this for awhile lol

Comment: I suspected a colorblind person would have trouble, but I didn't know.

Comment: +1 I would totally be in support of this.

Answer (score 11):

Agreed...the contrast is even worse on my crappy laptop at home.  A solid box like SU would be much appreciated.

Which one has the accepted answer?

[alt text http://i36.tinypic.com/mw9p94.png](http://i36.tinypic.com/mw9p94.png)